# Wildfly 16 with http-remoting behind NGINX: JBREM000202

Tags: nginx, wildfly

I am trying to put Wildfly 16 behind NGINX as a reverse proxy. I want to serve EJBs using http-remoting with it.

Here's my NGINX configuration:

```
server {                                                                                                                             
  listen          81;                                                                                                                
  server_name     10.0.2.15;                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                     
  location / {                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                     
    set $should_proxy "";                                                                                                            
    set $upgrade_header "";

    if ($http_sec_jbossremoting_key) {
      set $should_proxy "Y";
    }

    if ($should_proxy = Y) {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      set $upgrade_header "upgrade";
    }

    proxy_set_header Sec-JbossRemoting-Key $http_sec_jbossremoting_key;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Connection $upgrade_header;
    
  }
}
```

However, on the EJB client I am getting

```
IOException: JBREM000202: Abrupt close on Remoting connection
```

I tried getting the headers produced by NGINX and used tcpdump with following output:

```
00:16:08.083162 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 34533, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 185)
    localhost.34890 > localhost.http-alt: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfead (incorrect -> 0x81b5), seq 1:134, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 1104278851 ecr 1104278851], length 133: HTTP, length: 133
        GET / HTTP/1.0
        Sec-JbossRemoting-Key: iy2PuEO5anDKgm4w2+o0Tw==
        Upgrade: jboss-remoting
        Host: 10.0.2.15:81
        Connection: upgrade

00:16:08.083165 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 42808, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.http-alt > localhost.34890: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x753d), ack 134, win 511, options [nop,nop,TS val 1104278851 ecr 1104278851], length 0
00:16:08.083690 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 42809, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 227)
    localhost.http-alt > localhost.34890: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfed7 (incorrect -> 0x1ada), seq 1:176, ack 134, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 1104278852 ecr 1104278851], length 175: HTTP, length: 175
        HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
        Connection: Upgrade
        Upgrade: jboss-remoting
        Sec-JbossRemoting-Accept: ofI3qxa1miPoq1vhp3tDCO5r/kw=
        Date: Sat, 20 Jun 2020 22:16:08 GMT
```

Compared to the requests sent directly to Wildfly, they look identical. I have no idea how to further debug this.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how my nginx config looks like, and it works:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.6:9990;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

        #for proxying wildfly
        proxy_set_header sec_jbossremoting_key $http_sec_jbossremoting_key;
        proxy_set_header sec_hornetqremoting_key $http_sec_hornetqremoting_key;
        proxy_set_header upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header host $http_host;
    }
```

You can debug by executing the **jboss-cli.sh** script and see if you can connect.

First, try to send the request to the wildfly directly, in my case is 127.0.0.6:9990

```
[user@server]# /opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --controller=127.0.0.6:9990 --connect
[standalone@127.0.0.6:9990 /] version
JBoss Admin Command-line Interface
```

Than, try to connect by nginx, in my case is 172.16.20.11:9990

```
[user@server]# /opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --controller=172.16.20.11:9990 --connect
[standalone@172.16.20.11:9990 /] version
```

Running the script will show you what kind of errors you have in there, not the nginx :)

Comment: Thank you so much, catalin! This is working!

Comment: so enjoy it :))